# Hide language drop down menu in Qualtrics on specific questions

Tags: javascript, hide, qualtrics

I need to hide the language dropdown menu on some specific questions on Qualtrics. I remember there is a javascript for it, but I cannot find it anymore.

I tried looking at the Qualtrics community website, but it is currently down.

Thank you.